# Setup non-MS email (gmail) in Windows 8 Mail app

Tags: email, windows-8

All documentation I have found online seems to apply to an older or different version of Windows 8.  I am using the 90 evaluation copy of [Windows 8 Enterprise](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/jj554510.aspx).  Is it disabled because it is the enterprise edition?

Basically, I can start the Mail app, bring up the settings (<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>), but all I am given for options are `Permissions` and `Rate and Review`.  In other documentation I've seen this is where you add an account.

Is this possible? If this is a restriction to Windows 8 Enterprise, is there a trial version of normal Home editions somewhere?

Comment: It's certainly not a limitation of Enterprise edition as that's what I'm using here and I have it configured for my Exchange account with options to add Google, Hotmail and other accounts... Are you signed in with a Microsoft Account? And is the evaluation Activated?

Comment: @GrahamWager I'm not sure if it's activated.  I am *not* signed in with an MS account.  I went in thinking I would just use gmail from the get go.  Maybe an MS account is required? Will try and find out.

Comment: Apparently that was it.  Need to be signed in with an MS account to do *anything* with those built in apps, like Mail.  That's very disappointing.

Comment: Glad I could help. I'll post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the Mail app (and many of the other build in apps) even with other providers, you will need a Microsoft account linked to your user account (or have signed in with a Microsoft account).

To link a Microsoft account to your user account:

- press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and select Change PC settings from the bottom of the menu:

  [image: Change PC settings option]
- select the Users option:

  [image: Users option]
- click Connect your Microsoft account in the Your account section:

  [image: Connect your Microsoft account button]
- follow the instructions on-screen

Answer (score 3):

You just need to set it up - open up the mail client, open up the charm bar, select, settings then accounts, and select "google". Type in your e mail address and password when you're done and thats it.

[image]

It is *unrelated* to your microsoft account, which incidentally just uses any e mail address.

Comment: That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

That is actually incorrect. You do not have to have a microsoft account to use the mail application. You can turn off applications requiring an account and sign in with whatever email you wish. Though you will need to know the server settings and domain settings if it doesn't automatically configure.